# Как достать значение из квадратных скобок в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, requests

```
import requests
import json
r1 = input()
url = 'https://gotiny.cc/api'
payload = {
  "input": r1,
}
r = requests.post(url, json=payload)

result = r.text
print(result)
```

Впишем в r1 - https://example.org и получим:

```
[{"long":"example.org","code":"dnnw7h"}]
```

Но мне нужно достать значение `code`
Помогите!

Comment: `json.loads(result)[0]["code"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте метод [`json`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content), чтобы преобразовать ответ в объект Python. После этого вы можете получить значение так же, как получили бы его из обычного словаря:

```py
result = r.json()[0]['code']
print(result)  # dnnw7h
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо обратиться к первому элементу списка (это он в квадратных скобках), а затем к ключу словаря ("code").

Примерно так, если на печать вывод:

```
result = [{"long":"example.org","code":"dnnw7h"}]
print (result[0]["code"])  # dnnw7h
```

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @andreymal, вы что-то не то в `result` ввели, вероятно. Нет тут `TypeError`. Да и ответ у меня аналогичен вашему, только с пояснениями (мы их синхронно писали, я не воровал:-)

Comment: Это вы выдумали какой-то свой result, который отличается от result из вопроса

Comment: import requests
import json
r1 = input()
url = 'https://gotiny.cc/api'
payload = {
  "input": r1,
}
r = requests.post(url, json=payload)

result = r.text
print(result[0]["code"])

После него ошибка та же, что написал @andreymal

Comment: Ну а самый правильный ответ дал всё равно nomnoms12

Comment: @andreymal да, вы правы

Comment: Было написано: "и получим: [{"long":"example.org","code":"dnnw7h"}]" (на печати, исходя из логики). Чтобы такое получить, надо иметь result, как у меня.

Comment: @Сергей это не так, принт вашего result выдаёт совершенно другой результат. Чтобы получить принт как в вопросе, result может быть только строкой

Comment: @andreymal, ничего не понимаю. Беру две строки кода из моего ответа, копирую их в PyCharm и IDLE, оба выдают на выходе `dnnw7h`. Не надо `result` быть строкой для этого.

Comment: @Сергей ну если вы работаете со своим собственным выдуманным result, то конечно же у вас всё работает :) У автора вопроса ваш ответ не работает, потому что настоящий result из вопроса - это строка

Comment: @Сергей, поле text результата запроса всегда содержит строку. То что она через print выглядит как валидный словарь еще не означает, что это словарь.

Comment: @andreymal, теперь ясно, спасибо:-)  Да, логический скачок, говорю про печать, а работаю с переменной.